# How can i display a navigation bar across multiple webpages?

Tags: php, html, css

I know CSS and HTML to a reasonable degree, but I've never built a multi-page website before.

I have a header area of my site coded, and want it to display it across multiple webpages. How can I do this?

Comment: If you have Visual Studio or are interested in .Net, you can easily do that with masterpages.

Comment: Bear in mind that for both php and jsp (and really any sort of includes) you have to be running a live server (typically Apache via WAMP, MAMP, XAMPP, or something live).

Comment: Are you using Dreamweaver?

Comment: I have web hosting, where these files will be going. Is that enough for this?

Comment: In case you are using PHP files, the solution given in the first answer by @BeatAlex should work. If your pages are HTML-only, you can use the legacy pre-html5 tag `frameset`. I recommend the PHP approach, it is more usable and the html approach is already deprecated in html5.

Answer (score 2):

Save it as `header.php`/`header.html` whichever one you need. Then, from every file you code from then on, you can `<?php include('header.php');?>`. The files you include in HAVE to be `.php` or it wont work.

Comment: I don't know much about PHP, and have no other use for it currently so I'm not preparing to learn it right now. So forgive me for this beginner question, but can a php file contain html and css? i.e. can I use it just like a regular .html file?

Comment: Yes you can, a php file uses <?php ?>. Anything INSIDE them brackets is php, anything OUTSIDE the brackets is HTML. (well technically anything outside the <?php ?> is sent as output. but this output can be anything you want. HTML, XML, Javascript, Json. and thats only text. It can also output binary, and tell the browser how to interpret it(pdf, image, etc))

Comment: You just need to learn enough PHP to use the `inlcude` function.  `.php` files can contain regular HTML, CSS and JavaScript just like `.html` pages.

Comment: PHP isn't difficult. Crack on and learn it. Google `php for beginners`

Comment: What would I need to put in the header.html file? Would I need to include <html> and <body> brackets, or just the header code?

Comment: Basically, `header.html` would include everything up until the `<body>` tag, then the `php` folder you can treat as a normal html file except that one `include` line. :)

Answer (score 0):

Same applies to jsp if for any reason php didnt work or you fancied a change of pace

Create a file called header.jsp then use the tag below when you want to include it on a page.

```
<jsp:include page="{header.jsp}"/>
```

This is maybe of no use to you but who knows it may help someone. Some people find this easier and some find this harder it depends on your programming background.

Answer (score 0):

Use a web programming language (PHP / ASP.Net / Whatever you like) to include the navigation bar in all the pages. There are template languages like Twig that can do that for you in a smarter way and provide you with additional template features, if you might need them.